# Spring MVC form taglib support for nested objects

Tags: spring, forms, jsp, spring-mvc, taglib

My entitiy looks like this

```
public class UserDTO {
    private String Name;
    // other fields

    private List<Address> addresses;

    // other fields

}
```

I can bind addresses field from my JSP like this:

```
<select multiple="multiple"  name="addresses.line1" ></select>
```

But I would like to use spring form taglib in my JSP. what is the equivalent of path? path="addresses.line1" is not supported.

Comment: did you import `<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>` in your jsp page on top?

Comment: Try using `path="addresses[0].line1`. Add some index value to it. Maybe you can generate it by jstl.

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
public class UserDTO {
    private String Name;
    private List<Address> addresses;
    // other fields
}
UserDTO user = new ...
model.addAttribute("userDTO", user);
```

and in your jsp:

```
//import taglib

<form:form action="/myaction" ...>
  <form:select id="address" name="address" path="Address">
    <c:forEach items="${userDTO.addresses}" var="addresses">
        <form:option value="${addresses.XXX}" label="${addresses.YYYY}"/>
    </c:forEach>
```